# How to scroll to an element while keeping it vertically centered in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Lets say I have an element within a parent container. I want to scroll to that element, while keeping it vertically centered in the parent container. I wrote the following function that works on all browsers except for IE11:

```
// Function for scrolling to an element, and placing it in the middle of the view
// By default, the container parameter is set to the browser window
function scrollIntoViewMiddle(element, container) {
    if (container === undefined) {
        container = window;
    }
    var elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var absoluteElementTop = elementRect.top;
    var middleDiff = (elementRect.height / 2);
    var scrollTopOfElement = absoluteElementTop + middleDiff;
    var scrollY = scrollTopOfElement - (window.innerHeight / 2);
    container.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work on IE11, as `scrollTo()` is not a defined function or whatever. What is the alternative approach? Is there even a way to do this in IE11?

Comment: Use a `scrollTo` polyfill library, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-behavior-polyfill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [the scrollTo method doesn't support IE browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo), we could set the [Element.scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) property and [Element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) property to achieve the same effect.

Please refer to the following sample code:

```
<script>
    function scrollWin() {
        var con = document.getElementById("container");
        var el = document.getElementById("goose");
        scrollIntoViewMiddle(el, con);
    }

    function scrollIntoViewMiddle(element, container) {
        if (container === undefined) {
            container = window;
        }
        var elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        var absoluteElementTop = elementRect.top;
        var middleDiff = (elementRect.height / 2);
        var scrollTopOfElement = absoluteElementTop + middleDiff;
        var scrollY = (scrollTopOfElement - (container.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2));
        //container.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
        container.scrollLeft = 0;
        container.scrollTop = scrollY;
    }
</script>
```

Html resource and CSS style:

```
<style>
    .scrollContainer {
        overflow-y: auto;
        max-height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 120px;
    }

    .box {
        margin: 5px;
        background-color: yellow;
        height: 25px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    #goose {
        background-color: lime;
    }
</style>
<div id="container" class="scrollContainer">
    <div class="box">duck</div>
    <div class="box">duck</div>
    <div class="box">duck</div>
    <div class="box">duck</div>
    <div class="box">duck</div>
    <div class="box">duck</div>
    <div class="box">duck</div>
    <div class="box">duck</div>
    <div id="goose" class="box">goose</div>
    <div class="box">duck</div>
    <div class="box">duck</div>
    <div class="box">duck</div>
    <div class="box">duck</div>
    <div class="box">duck</div>
    <div class="box">duck</div>
    <div class="box">duck</div>
    <div class="box">duck</div>
</div>
<button onclick="scrollWin()">Click me to scroll</button><br><br>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]